# How does Android audit file actions?

Tags: applications, file-system, logging

I was wondering if there is a log of when an application read or write data. Furthermore, how would I go about accessing this data? If there is none, is there another way you guys would think of logging applications creating or opening files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do certain checks using the stock logging software's, ( MTK Logger, Android Info Etc.. )

### The quickest way to see your logs is by calling `*#*#info#*#*` or `*#*#4636#*#*` Notice the opposition's `*#` and `#*`

You could hypothetically log this information using a folder change watcher on your internal SD like

### [Folder Sync Free on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)

### [Folder Sync Full on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full&hl=en)

---

Ok Here is what to do

1. Install FolderSync
2. Create a New Folder Pair.
3. Call the Pair ( Error Invoke ) or something rememberable.
4. Edit the Filter At Bottom to Filter Everything or `.*`
5. Now set it's sync method to Instant ( file change sync )

---

Ok so hypothetically, FolderSync will start a sync caused by the recent file changes or folder additions and deletions... The sync will

- notice changed folders/files
- start a blank sync
- log the sync details
- Open the log for file change history
- see changed files

---

This method could work, but it's just hypothetical. I use FolderSync for way more than just synchronized folders !

Comment: Great info! Will look into this!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, and I don't think there's any way to achieve this as a user without making your own custom ROM.